# Error 'not subscriptable' when calling the function

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have the function below that copies a file in a directory and recreate it in the directory where the function is called. When I am running the code part by part in ipython, it is working fine. However, when I execute it as a function it is giving me the following error:

```
---> 17     shutil.copy2(filein[0], os.path.join(dir,'template.in'))

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the function

```
import os
import shutil
from find import find

def recreatefiles(filedir):
    currdir = os.getcwd() # get current directory
    dirname = 'maindir'
    dir = os.path.join(currdir,dirname)
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)

    #Copy .in files and create a template
    filein = find('*.in',filedir) # find is a function created

    shutil.copy2(filein[0], os.path.join(dir,'template.in'))
```

Any ideas about the error? Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code for find

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                if not name.startswith('.'):
                    result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
```

EDIT2: Output of filein from ipython

```
  [1]: filein
  [2]: ['/home/Projects/test.in']
```

Basically, there is just one file. I used filein[0] in shutil.copy2 to remove the square brackets

Comment: There's probably an error in `find`. Post its source code.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get `'type' object is not subscriptable` with this code. You can, however, get `list index out of range` if `filein` is empty.

Comment: Hmm, `find` is perfectly fine. I don't see the error either.

Comment: What @aix says is correct, make sure your posted code matches *exactly* with the code that gives the error.

Comment: Please print out what filein is in recreatefiles after it's returned from find.  My suspicions are that (1) it's actually the "file" object, and it'll show up as <type 'file'>, and (2) this isn't the code which is actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can possibly get `'type' object is not subscriptable` with this code (as a matter of fact, I can successfully run it on my computer and have it copy one file).

This suggests that the code you're running isn't the code that you *think* you're running.

I would do two things:

1. make sure that the code is *exactly* as it appears in your question;
2. since you appear to be running this in an interactive shell, make sure you close and restart `ipython` (to eliminate the possibility that you're accidentally calling an older version of `find()` that got imported earlier).

As a side note, I'd explicitly handle the case where `filein` is empty: the current code would raise an exception (`list index out of range`).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import pdb
pdb.pm()
```

just after getting the exception to be able to pinpoint exactly which line of code in which file triggers the error, and what variable is a `type` being subscripted.